# install4j - insufficient disk space error

Tags: install4j

I've just solved a problem with install4j and want to share the solution. And I hope that this problem will be fixed by install4j developers.

So, I had next situation:

OS Win7 Professional, there was some install4j installer which I launched. Immediately after launching I got "insufficient disk space" error, but computer had about 400 GB available hard disk space. I had a complete misunderstanding.

Actually the problem wasn't related to disk space. I had windows user account in Russian, then I created new user account in English and it helped.

I suspect that install4j can't create temporary files in path with Russian letters.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Install4J instalation issue and should be posted on Install4J web site or some Install4J bug database

Comment: This is a *question and answer site*, which means that there must first be a *question*, and then people post *answers* to that question. While it's nice you want to share the information, you need to do it properly. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for details about how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround - use an earlier version of install4j to compile your installers. Installers compiled with version 5.1.6 for example - don't have this problem.